# Convert VARCHAR2 to TIMESTAMP in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a VARCHAR2 value in the format '14-SEP-11 12.33.48.537150 AM' and I need to convert this to a TIMESTAMP as is. That is like,

```
SELECT TO_DATE('14-SEP-11 12.33.48.537150 AM', '<format_string>') FROM DUAL;
```

I want the return from the above query to be '14-SEP-11 12.33.48.537150 AM' in TIMESTAMP data format.

What should be the 'format_string' for this.

Please help since I tried many things but none works.. :(

I am using Oracle 11gR2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DATE and TIMESTAMP are two different datatypes.  So you need to use the correct conversion function for each, which in your case would be [TO_TIMESTAMP()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions211.htm).

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('14-SEP-11 12.33.48.537150 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') 
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: If we specify HH24 it gives an error. It has to be HH since I need it as AM/PM. Anyway thanks this worked with HH.

Comment: @BathiyaPriyadarshana - oops, force of habit: I always work with the twenty-four hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

```
select from_tz(to_timestamp('14-SEP-11 12.33.48.537150 PM', 'DD-Mon-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'), 'EUROPE/LONDON') from dual
```